# Given the array used with ng-repeat, can I select an individual item created with each item?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, openlayers

I have an angular app that builds a list of zones from map data. The zones are displayed both in a sidebar in divs using ng-repeat, and on the map as vector features. When a user selects a zone on the map, I need to scroll to that zone's DIV in the sidebar. jQuery can perform a scrollTo action given an element, and I know which zone is selected; can I get a reference to the DIV that matches that item?

I cannot use an index because there may be sorting or filtering on the ng-repeat array. Any other options?

EDIT:

Here's some relevant code:

```
<div class="turf"
    ng-repeat="zone in layers.zones.features"
    ng-class="{
        selected: zone === selectedZone && zone !== highlightedZone,
        hover: zone === highlightedZone
    }"
    ng-click="selectZone(zone); $event.stopPropagation()">

    <h2>{{zone.name}}</h2>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="zone.name" />
    {{zone.users}} users present
</div>
```

Openlayers will call a function when one of those zones on the map is clicked:

```
zoneLayer.events.register("featureselected", null, function(e){
    var zone=e.feature;
    var element = null; // how do I get the element?

    $(element).scrollTo(); // or similar
});
```

Comment: Please post some of your code. What you'll want to do is attach a unique id to each sidebar div, and store that id somewhere in the corresponding map zone -- but how you do that depends entirely on how you're generating the map.

Comment: This might help with the actual scrolling: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$anchorScroll

Comment: I'll post some code, but it's pretty generic ng-repeat stuff, and the handler is all OpenLayers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your zone objects have ID or some other identifier then add ID to your div

```
<div class="turf"
    id="{{zone.ID}}"
    ng-repeat="zone in layers.zones.features"
    ng-class="{
        selected: zone === selectedZone && zone !== highlightedZone,
        hover: zone === highlightedZone
    }"
    ng-click="selectZone(zone); $event.stopPropagation()">

    <h2>{{zone.name}}</h2>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="zone.name" />
    {{zone.users}} users present
</div>
```

Then find your zone by id

```
zoneLayer.events.register("featureselected", null, function(e){
    var zone=e.feature;
    var element = $("#" + zone.ID); // how do I get the element?

    $(element).scrollTo(); // or similar
});
```

If you can't afford to add IDs to divs then add `data-zoneID` attribute and find element by that attribute `var element = $("div[data-zoneID=" + zone.ID + "]");`